# Get elements in the path of a touch event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, touch

I have a grid of squares. I want the user to be able to touch and move across the grid, and each square to change colour when the touch goes over it.

I've looked at `onTouchStart`, `onTouchMove` and `onTouchEnd`. Using `onTouchMove`, the `event.target` is always the element where the touch began.

How can I find the elements that are moved over with the touch?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abby_io/mtq6xfx4/22/)

Comment: Maybe `pointer-events: none;` can help.. just change the dragged element style to that when start dragging and move it back when dragging stops

Comment: I will clarify the question - there are no elements being dragged

Comment: Ok, i see.. why not just use the `onTouchStart` event in each square.. does that work? or better: use canvas.

Comment: onTouchStart only fires when the touch starts, not on each element hit. Canvas is suboptimal because it vastly increases the complexity of redraws and all other features I'm building on top. I'm running this experiment/prorotype in an attempt to drop canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this as follows;

#### Added `onTouchMove` onto the wrapping element

`<div onTouchMove={this.onTouch}>`

#### Handle that touchMove event by calculating the child position

```
onTouch: function(e) {
  const coords={
    x: parseInt(e.touches[0].pageX/boxSize, 10),
    y: parseInt(e.touches[0].pageY/boxSize, 10)
  }
  this.handleChildChange(coords.x, coords.y);
}
```

This calculates the coordinates of the box and triggers the colour change

```
handleChildChange: function(x, y) {
  this.props.grid[y][x].c=1;
  this.forceUpdate()
}
```

#### Box `onMouseEnter` for mouse handling

```
onMouseEnter={this.props.handleChange.bind(this, this.props.box.x, this.props.box.y)}
```

On each box item, I keep the `onMouseEnter` so that both touch and mouse move are handled in the same way

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abby_io/hztct4d4/4/)

Comment: "<a class='gotoLine' href='#61:11'>61:11</a> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&lt;'" --- Fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Try to add another element (top of the squares) that covers all squares and handle your touch events in that element. Then just calculate the position of the underlaying square. Use Z-index to put that event handling grid at the top.

Like:

```html
<div style={{position: 'relative'}}>
  <div onTouchMove={this.log} style={{position: 'absolute', zIndex: 1000}}>
  </div>
  <div className="square" />
  <div className="square" />
  <div className="square" />
  <div className="square" />
  ...
</div>
```

So if you have like 10x10 squares with 20px X 20px that top div should be 200px X 200px. That can be calculated dynamically too.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/abby_io/1au1ee3L/ - I added onTouchMove to the wrapping `div` but as you can see it still only shows the element where the touch started

Comment: Edited the answer.. so of course you shouldn't add those squares inside that event handling grid otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thanks. When you say 'calculate the position of the underlying square', do you mean use the pageX, pageY and then `document.elementFromPoint` to pull out those elements and manipulate the dom outside of the framework? I think I can achieve that same thing without the extra div just using `onTouchMove` then `e.touches[0].pageX` but ideally I dont want to be doing my own dom manipulation

Comment: no, because you know the size of that event handling element and number of squares you can just calculate it without pageX etc

Comment: The part I'm not following is how I would calculate that. I need the position in order to do so surely

Comment: You know the finger position in that top div (local position) so you can just divide that position with amount of squares. Like top div: 100px X 100px, square is 10px X 10px and finger is at x:25,y:6 then finger is top of third square from left top.

Comment: How do I reference/access the finger position if not with `e.touches[0].pageX`? And also how do I then trigger the react component method from the element

Comment: I have it working in this fiddle but didn't need to use an extra div and still had to use `.pageX` https://jsfiddle.net/abby_io/hztct4d4/